# How concatenate value and some prefix before get it into src attribute?

Tags: jquery, html, attributes, concatenation

I want to show image of according goods for admin page from database and queried images located in one level up folder but in database path to image for main page i have such type of path `img/other/hands.jpg` and for admin page i need prefix `../img/other/hands.jpg`

I tried to concat "../" + data.img but it didn't work.
data.img is path to image taken from database i.e "img/other/hands.jpg"

HTML

```
<div class="img-container"><img src="" alt="Картинка"></div>
```

JS/JQuery

```
$("img").attr("src", "../" + data.img);
```

Maybe I typed quiet messy explanation though code is pretty clear

Comment: The path to your image needs to be relative to the location of your HTML page. Hard code the image path to see what works, then modify your code to create the exact same string.  Also, watch your developer console and use it to your benefit.  And/or show us some code so it's obvious how these snippets you've provided actually work in context.

Comment: I understood about relative path and doing changes in developer console i saw that i need such path "../img/other/hands.jpg" which is load image for my admin folder instead of this hard coded path "img/other/hands.jpg" which works only for main index.php in upper folder. 
So i need to concat "../" and "data.img" and load this value into src attribute using jquery but my example showed earlier not working and i get usual path "img/other/hands.jpg" without "../"